# What are the topics in noncommutative algebraic geometry?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, big-list, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

**Preface:** I know very little about noncommutative algebra and noncommutative geometry, so please feel free to make improvement suggestions for my question. Also, to my knowledge there are several flavours of algebra-geometry duality in the noncommutative world, like how one has the equivalence $\mathsf{CRings}^{\mathrm{op}} \cong \mathsf{Sch}^{\mathrm{aff}}$ in commutative algebraic geometry (Gelfand Duality comes to mind), so I will be thinking of noncommutative algebra as the "affine" version of noncommutative (algebraic) geometry. Again, feel free to correct me.

**Main question:**

1. What are the main branches of noncommutative (algebraic) geometry and what are their relations to representation theory (I'm particularly interested in Geometric Langlands in the sense of Gaitsgory et al.) ? I've heard of buzzwords like "chiral algebras" and "deformation quantisation" but I'm too unfamiliar with the literature to be able to draw up some sort of mindmap of these various topics.
2. Also, what are the relationships between the classical theory of noncommutative rings, that of Lie algebras and universal algebras, along with the representation theory of (finite) groups and the modern theory of "noncommutative spaces" via monoidal categories of sheaves over base spaces (again, things in quotations are just buzzwords to me right now) ?
3. Lastly, in which of the branches are the technical tools like Koszul Duality used ?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried searching google for “introduction to noncommutative geometry”, “survey of noncommutative geometry”, etc?

Comment: For instance, there is Rosenberg's "Noncommutative Algebraic Geometry and Representations of Quantized Algebras" (1995).

Comment: @ZachTeitler I have, yes. I've also skimmed some of the documents I've been able to find, such as Beilinson and Drinfeld's "Chiral Algebra", Connes' "Noncommutative Geometry", or Rosenberg's "Noncommutative spaces". It's not that I'm having trouble finding references, but rather, trouble organising said references.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I will check that out. Thank you.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg After going through it for a bit, I must say that Rosenberg's "Noncommutative Algebraic Geometry and Representations of Quantized Algebras" is a very good reference. Thank you for the suggestion.